# PHP Model View Controller (MVC) Active Reconrd methods

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model-view-controller

I am building my own PHP MVC framework. (https://github.com/carlinoo/Vinum) I was wondering how I can do something similar to Rails Active Record.

For example:

```
Book.where('reserved = true').limit(10).offset(5)
```

This will translate to

```
SELECT * FROM Book WHERE reserved = true LIMIT 10 OFFSET 5;
```

Because those class methods are linked, it all evaluates to that SQL statement. I can't find how to make linked class methods to interact between each other in PHP. I created this class FlowingQuery that extends ArrayObject to act like an array, but I still don't know how to have classes interacting with each other. At the moment I have a `where` class method that returns all objects in an array, then `limit` that counts the number of objects in the array returned and only return 10 of them.

That is not actually translated into SQL.

Any ideas or advice?

Thank you

Comment: Check Laravel's Eloquent ORM, it implements the ActiveRecord pattern in PHP https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent

Comment: Don't. [Active Record](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/activeRecord.html) is an antipattern, because it violates SRP by merging domain business logic and persistence logic in the same class. It makes it exceedingly had to test, suffers from performance issues, when DB schema becomes complex, and accumulates complexity. You should be adopting [Data Mapper](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html) pattern.

Comment: @arieljuod That was a good resource.

Comment: @tereško what do you recommend? any resources I can read? Thanks both for your time

Comment: @CarlinoGonzalez reading [PoEAA book](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Enterprise-Application-Architecture-Addison-Wesley-Signature/dp/0321127420) would be a good start. It's where those two previously linked excepts are from.

Answer (score -1):

If the methods are in the same class, then to make them chainable the chainable methods need to return $this.

```
public function doSomething()
{
    // Do stuff

    return $this;
}
```